# How to calculate the distance between two points when x and y have different ranges?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points in which the point's coordinates have different ranges, i. e., $0 < x < 1000$ and $0 < y < 100.$

So far, I've been using the Euclidean distance formula to calculate this distance:

$d = \sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^2 + (y_{1}-y_{2})^2}$.

Is this the correct way to calculate the distance between two points given these conditions?

Should I normalize x and y so both of them can only have values between zero and 1?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your approach (without normalization) is correct.  The ranges of potential values have nothing to do with the distance between two points, any more than the distance between two points on a road surface would depend upon the fact that the road is very long but not very wide.

Comment: It sounds like you have a specific application in mind.  Of course the distance between the points still comes from that formula.  If you are doing some statistics related project, like using KNN to predict something, you should normalize.

Comment: @KidA424 I'm trying to use this formula as a proximity measure for an implementation of k-means. The formula is used to calculate the distance between a point in the dataset and the center of a cluster.

Comment: If you talk about distance I assume you may place the x,y on a Cartesian  system, which has the origin (0,0) as mutual point. I would say that for your case the distance calculation is: $\sqrt( x^2+y^2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are performing k-means clustering, I would suggest doing some kind of normalization.  Consider a more extreme case, where $y$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1000000$.  All that will end up mattering, if you use Euclidean distance, is the $x$-values.  The chances of a $y$-value having a significant effect on one point's distance from another is miniscule.  So, mathematically, your $y$-variable is considered irrelevant.

Do you want your $y$-variable to be irrelevant?  Is your $x$-variable roughly 10 times as important as your $y$?  If not, then you should normalize.